# No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[List[models.Product]]

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm starting to play with Play! Framework for Scala and trying to build a JSON REST API with MongoDB.

I'm using [play-mongodb-driver](https://github.com/evojam/play-mongodb-driver) and trying to build the findAll method for my API.

So I have this model:

```
//models/product.scala                                                                                                                                      
case class Product(_id: String, name: String, price: Double)                                                                           
                                                                                                                                       
object Product {                                                                                                                       
  val collection = MongoClients.create().database("shopping").collection("products")                                                   
  implicit val format = Json.format[Product]    

  def findAll = {                                                                                                                      
    collection.find().collect[Product]                                                                                                
  }  
}
```

And this controller:

```
//controllers/Product.scala

class Products @Inject()(mongo: MongoClient) extends Controller {                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
  import models._                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
  def listProducts = Action.async {                                                                                             
    Json.toJson(Product.findAll)                                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

and all I got is this error:

```
No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[List[models.Product]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

How can I make this works?

I saw in some examples people implementing `implicti val format = Json.format[Model]` and thought this could solve the problem, but it didn't...

Comment: Looks like Product.findAll returns  Future, so try Product.findAll.map { allProducts => Json.toJson(allProducts) }

Comment: Solved part of the problem! But now it says that the overloaded method "apply" cannot be applied

Comment: hmm how about Ok(Json.toJson(allProducts))

Comment: Just got this: ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, scala.MatchError: play.modules.enabled += "com.evojam.MongoModule" (of class java.lang.String)
  while locating play.api.inject.PluginsProvider
  while locating play.api.Plugins
    for parameter 7 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:240)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:240)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

Comment: after a google and look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610945/provisionexception-using-playframework-2-4-2   I'd guess you've got something going wrong with your DI.  However you are  both injecting a mongoClient in the controller and seemingly only using the collection in the Product companion object.  Maybe you don't need to inject the mongo client in the controller?

Comment: My DI? What should be my DI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95972/discussion-between-gbrennon-and-corn-dog).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what is Product.findAll method but it looks like this method returns

```
Future[List[Product]]
```

The problem is that you trying to serialize Future to json, but you should serialize the result of Future like this:

```
def listProducts = Action.async {
  Product
    .findAll
    .map(Json.arr(_))
    .map(arr => Ok(arr(0)))
}
```

Comment: didn't work :( Now I have this "Cannot write an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult]"

Comment: @gbrennon It works for me without ".map(Json.arr(_))".